# Align stacked bar charts usind pandas

Tags: python, pandas, stacked

I'm trying to align all of the stacked bar charts having the same index.
What's the best way of doing this?

[image: stacked_bar_plots]

This is my code so far:

```
xantho99 = [545/60, 6/60, 1688/60, 44/60]
buch99 = [51/60, 2/60, 576/60, 7/60]
myco99 = [519/60, 9/60, 889/60, 28/60]
cory99 = [247/60, 5/60, 1160/60, 28/60]
xantho90 = [545/60, 8/60, 989/60, 27/60]
buch90 = [51/60, 3/60, 523/60, 5/60]
myco90 = [519/60, 11/60, 802/60, 32/60]
cory90 = [247/60, 7/60, 899/60, 27/60]
xanthouc = [545/60, 0/60, 5407/60, 193/60]
buchuc = [51/60, 0/60, 1014/60, 20/60]
mycouc = [519/60, 0/60, 4644/60, 101/60]
coryuc = [247/60, 0/60, 2384/60, 77/60]
df = pd.DataFrame([xantho, xantho99, xantho90, buch, buch99, buch90, myco, myco99, myco90, cory, cory99, cory90], columns=['Prodigal', 'Cd-hit', 'PSOT', 'Zusammenführen'], index=["X", "X","X", "B", "B","B", "M", "M","M", "C", "C","C"])
df.columns.name = "Abschnitt"
current_palette = "blue", "green", "red", "yellow"
ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=True, title="Zeitbedarf der einzelnen Abschnitte (Xanthomonas)", xlim=(0, sum(xantho)*1.1), color=current_palette, rot=0)
ax.set_xlabel("Zeit in Stunden")
```

Thank You!

Comment: By align do you mean you want to combine all of the 3 bars labeled with `X` into one single bar, with the red/blue/green/yellow values all added together?

Comment: no just want to keep no space in between them

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant code (should work if you put it at the bottom of the script in the question):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
...
...
# Comment out old plot
# ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=True, title="Zeitbedarf der einzelnen Abschnitte (Xanthomonas)", xlim=(0, sum(xantho)*1.1), color=current_palette, rot=0)                                                         
# ax.set_xlabel("Zeit in Stunden")                                                                                                                   
spacing = [0, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
p1 = plt.bar(np.arange(12) + spacing, df['Prodigal'], color="blue", width=1.0, edgecolor="black")
p2 = plt.bar(np.arange(12) + spacing, df['PSOT'], bottom=df['Prodigal'], color="red", width=1.0, edgecolor="black")
p3 = plt.bar(np.arange(12) + spacing, df['Zusammenführen'], bottom=df['Prodigal'] + df['PSOT'], color="yellow", width=1.0, edgecolor="black")
p4 = plt.bar(np.arange(12) + spacing, df['Cd-hit'], bottom=df['Prodigal'] + df['PSOT'] + df['Zusammenführen'], color="green", width=1.0, edgecolor="black")
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0], p4[0]), ('Prodigal', 'PSOT', 'Zusammenführen', 'Cd-hit'))
plt.show()
```

Here's what pops up after you run this snippet:

[image: Plot output]

I think this is what's desired, based on our discussion in comments. HTH, let me know if this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Thanks! But it should be like only the ones with the same Index aligned. Between different indexes there should be a gap.

Comment: It looks like `pandas` doesn't support having different widths out of the box. I think it probably should, I'll try to make a PR for pandas sometime tonight to fix the issue. In the meantime, I'll try to come up with a solution using `matplotlib`

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @davin it's not perfect, but should get you started. There's still some problems with the labels and such, but the grouping is at least there. This stuff doesn't really need to be hardcoded either, but I'll leave that as an exercise to you ;)

Comment: Also the legend is in the wrong order haha. I'll fix it later. HTH and that it's enough so that you can continue with your work. Good luck!